# javascript/selenium webdriver: Call a function synchronously after its completion infinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, async-await

I am making a program in Node using selenium webdriver. What it is supposed to do is:

```js
async function selenium() {
  try {
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText().then((value) => {
      recieved = value;
    });
    switch (recieved) {
      case "string1":
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("xpath"))).click().then(() => {}) break;
      case "p4":
        a = driver.findElement(By.className("xpath"));
        await exec("script1.exe", function(err) {
          if (err) {} else {}
        });
        break;
      case "p3":
        await exec("script2.exe", function(err) {
          if (err) {} else {}
        }) await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("xpath"))).click().then(() => {});
        break;
      case "p2":
        await exec("script3.exe", function(err) {
          if (err) {} else {}
        });
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("xpath"))).click().then(() => {});
        break;
      case "p1":
        await exec("script4.exe", function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("s5");
          }
        });
        break;
      default:
        selenium();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

What i want to do is, the program should run for the first time as specified and then the whole selenium function should repeat like the first time. What can i do to achieve this?

Comment: Put the function in a [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)? you can do infinite loop if you want

Comment: @Margon that leads to a memory leak!!

Comment: ofc you need a condition to stop the function... it can be a timer or something... I mean, I don't know your requirements, you just said "the selenium function should repeat like the first time". How many times? I don't know... I just said that if you want you can wrap it in a do ... while, then it's your business to check how many times and how to end it...